# What is the right way to organize a Django Project?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to wrap my head around how these apps are supposed to be organized. I have the following questions:

1. Are apps like `divs` that are generated separately?
2. Can we have apps within apps?
3. Can we have apps that when clicked on, change other apps with javascript?
4. Right now I just have one `views.py` file and it loads all of its content through different function calls.

   So right now I'm faced with if I should break up my `views.py` into smaller apps.
   Am I going about Django the correct way?
5. Are apps defined like the they are in picture below, or are apps supposed to act more like a page?
6. What if I want a header, breadcrumbs, and footer for all my pages? I'm super confused @.@

[image]

Comment: Read the Django tutorial. It should help with some of your questions.

Comment: What Django version are you using?  The 1.5 version (currently in alpha only) has some more guidance on how to lay out your app than other versions.

Comment: I think @user805981 is actually confused about the concept of templating, and not the reusable apps (what 1.5 added in tutorial). Apps are not responsible for making layout like illustrated in the picture). They can have reusable components to help in making certain portions in the layout (template tags or filters), but template is what makes layout, not apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apps have nothing whatsoever to do with divs. Django is not a CMS (although it can be used to create CMSs) and doesn't dictate the layout of your templates.

The usual way to handle different blocks on the page that need different logic to populate them is via [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/). James Bennett has a [good writeup](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/07/django-tips-write-better-template-tags/) on this, although the syntax is rather out of date so refer to the first link for that.